# How to fix Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux

Getting a error message saying `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function` from below code for Redux action.

What is the proper way to write this?

```
export async function getData() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(query))
      dispatch({ type: "DATA_AVAILABLE", data: data.data.listData.items });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `return (dispatch) => {` is not `async`

Comment: `return async (dispatch) => {`
no need of async in `export async function getData()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance also tried `export const getUserJournals = () => async (dispatch) => { ... } ` but didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `async` keyword for the `inner` function

```
export function getData() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(query))
      dispatch({ type: "DATA_AVAILABLE", data: data.data.listData.items });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! the error message went away but still doesn't get the data from API...

Comment: It actually seems to be working when it on my dev environment with AWS amplify but does not working on my local. Not sure why lol

Comment: It may so be the case that qraphql query isn't working correctly in your local

Comment: Have any idea to debug that on my local?

Comment: This works! I had an issue somewhere else. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull your await function out of your return function as well and pass `dispatch` as a param to `getData` function.

```
export async function getData(dispatch) {
  const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(query))
  dispatch({ type: "DATA_AVAILABLE", data: data.data.listData.items });
}
```

then you call it:

```
var dispatchFunc = function (params) {console.log(params);}
getData(dispatchFunc).then(function() {}).catch(function(err) { ... })
```

Comment: Getting `error:  TypeError: dispatch is not a function`

Comment: Updated my explaination

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function` this time.

Comment: But you should pass dispatch as fucntion